# Monitoring Docker with Check_MK

Tags: docker, monitoring, check-mk

I've installed both the agent and the piggyback plugin on the Docker Node and created the hosts on check_mk page, with the hostame pointed to the container ID, according to the https://mathias-kettner.com/cms_monitoring_docker.html documentation.

I can see the information for each running container but I can only see 3 services per container:

```
Check_MK
Check_MK Discovery
Docker container status
```

All other services shown on the documentation page and described as being automaticaly discovered, are not shown.

Do you have any clue of what it might be?

I'm using Check_MK RAW v1.5.0p9.

Answer (score 0):

if you feel free to share what you configured for piggyback would be useful.
But try this and share the output.

```
cmk -nvII hostname
```

-n - don't submit result to core
-v verbose 
-II reinventory